# Oracle SQL hierarchical query from bottom to top element

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical

In my table I store the successor of each entry.

```
+----+-----------+--+
| ID | SUCCESSOR |  |
+----+-----------+--+
|  1 |         2 |  |
|  2 |         3 |  |
|  3 |           |  |
+----+-----------+--+
```

I need to get from **ID 3** to **ID 1**.

I have tried to archieve this with the following query, but this does not work. :-(

```
SELECT NVL (id, 3)
FROM my_table
WHERE LEVEL = 1
CONNECT BY id = PRIOR successor
START WITH id = 3;
```

Can somebody please give me some advice how to get this working?

Comment: Remove `WHERE LEVEL = 1`. If this still doesn't work, replace `CONNECT BY id = PRIOR successor` with `CONNECT BY PRIOR id =  successor`

Comment: it works. thanks a lot!

Comment: @krokodilko If that solved the OP's problem, please post it as an answer and then OP accept it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following version should also provide the correct answer:

```
with my_table as 
(select 1 id, 2 successor from dual union
select 2 id, 3 successor from dual union
select 3 id, null successor from dual )
SELECT id FROM my_table
WHERE level = 3
CONNECT BY successor = PRIOR id 
START WITH successor is null
;
```